# How to close Safari from my App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, safari

Is that possible and if yes how can I close Safari which I had opened from my app itself.

If anyone knows please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you open it in UIWebView?

Comment: if it is not in web view..i dont think so we can close and go back to the app. dont know about latest 8.3 update if any

Comment: @SabrinaTuli: NO I open safari browser for UIWebview,

Answer (score 1):

You can't close other apps from your app.

But instead of opening Safari, you could open a view controller with a [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) to show the webpage you are opening in Safari.

Comment: i think IPC is provided in 8.x. may be we can work around.. If possible

Comment: @Rajan Even if IPC is introduced at some point in iOS 8, then I don't think Apple would allow you to close other apps.

Comment: yes i know.. hard luck.. just looking for a way.. :)

Comment: yes @Fogh is right, you can't colse other apps from your app and Apple would not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot.Except that safari browser has some sdks you can use.But in that case you must register your app's url scheme in your app in my opinion.